# Struct-like in python

Tags: python, oop, object

Using Python, I'm trying to write object that it's access would be like this:

```
page[2].records[7].color = "ffff"
```

(the 'record' has some fields).

the object should be exported to json string and of course import from json (currently unwrittten), so I've added the toString() method.

The point is the code is very "clumsy".  Is there way (using python) to make more "comely" code?

my code:

```
class Record ():
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self, title, color, action, data) :
        self.title = title
        self.color = color
        self.action = action
        self.data = data
    def toDict(self) :
        ans = {'title':self.title, 'color':self.color, 'action':self.action, 'data':self.data}
        return ans
    def toString(self):
        return '%s' % self.toDict()
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Records():
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.f_record = {}
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not(self.f_record.get(key,None)):
            self.f_record[key] = Record(None,None,None,None)
        return self.f_record[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.f_record[key] = value
    def toDict(self):
        ans = {}
        for i in self.f_record:
            ans[i] = self.f_record[i].toString()
        return ans
    def toString(self):
        return '%s' % self.toDict()
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Page():
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.records = Records()
    def toString(self):
        return self.records.toString()
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Papers():
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.f_papers = {}
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        if not (self.f_papers.get(key,None)):
            self.f_papers[key] = Page()
        return self.f_papers[key]
    def toString(self):
        ans = {}
        for i in self.f_papers:
            ans[i] = self.f_papers[i].toString()
        return '%s' % ans
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#tests

a = Papers()
a[1].records[1] = Record('group','red','open', 'group1')
a[1].records[2] = Record('group','green','open', 'group2')

a[2].records[7].title = "ffff"
a[1].records[1].title = 'title :-) '

print a[1].records[1].toString()
print a.toString()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you dislike about the code and what you want it to be like instead?

Comment: Your objects do nothing but store data. Do you need the classes in the first place? Do they have any methods besides `toString` and `toDict`?

Comment: One thing worth pointing out is that if you want to serialize to JSON you should use the `json` module instead of relying on `dict.__str__` (by the way if you want to return an object with its default string formatting you can just return `str(self.toDict())`).  A Python's dict representation looks close-enough to valid JSON most of the time, but there are corner cases that will bite you if you don't use a JSON library.

Comment: Additionally, this question seems a bit better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The code looks "to long" - I have 4 classes (instead of one or two), too much duplicated code (each class has the "toDict" and "toString" that actually are the same)   Blender - You are right, I need to store data, 'toString' and 'fromString' (or another good way to convert data and from json strings).  the 'toDict' is step on the way to 'toString'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dict` itself to make it a bit easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class PropertyDict (dict):
    def __getattr__ (self, attr):
        if self.has_key(attr):
            return self.__getitem__(attr)
        return object.__getattr(self, attr)

    def __setattr__ (self, attr, value):
        self.__setitem__(attr, value)

class Record (PropertyDict):
    def __init__ (self, title = None, color = None, action = None, data = None):
        self.title = title
        self.color = color
        self.action = action
        self.data = data

class Page (PropertyDict):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.records = defaultdict(Record)

papers = defaultdict(Page)
papers[1].records[1] = Record('group', 'red', 'open', 'group1')
papers[1].records[2] = Record('group', 'green', 'open', 'group2')

papers[2].records[7].title = "ffff"
papers[1].records[1].title = 'title :-) '

print(papers[1].records[1])
print(papers)
```

As the objects are now subtypes of `dict`, serializing it with json is simple. Only for deserializing you would have to write your own encode handler.

Comment: Tnx a lot.  this with J.F. Sebastian's (the usage of json) is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To serialize your object to json:

```
import json

json_text = json.dumps(your_obj.as_dict())
```

To create your object from json:

```
obj = YourClass.from_dict(json.loads(json_text))
```

You could easily implement the methods:

```
class YourClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, attrs):
        return cls(**attrs)
    def as_dict(self):
        return dict(self.__dict__)
    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.as_dict())
    def __repr__(self):
        # see http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace
        d = self.as_dict()
        items = ("{}={!r}".format(k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d))
        return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, ", ".join(items))
```

Example:

```
>>> obj = YourClass(title="foo", name="bar")
>>> obj.color = "ffffff"
>>> obj.name
'bar'
>>> obj
YourClass(color='ffffff', name='bar', title='foo')
>>> print(obj)
{"name": "bar", "color": "ffffff", "title": "foo"}
>>> obj.as_dict()
{'name': 'bar', 'color': 'ffffff', 'title': 'foo'}
```

You could define `from_json`, `as_json` methods if you'd like using the one-liners